# visual studio building error: unresolved external symbol _IID_IWICImagingFactory (MFC static lib)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mfc, unresolved-external

I wrote a porgram with a few standard dialogs in an SDI (Doc/View enabled) project.

Now that I want to send it to some friends i did set the `Use of MFC` `Use MFC in a static library`.

But when i try to build the solution i get the following error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IWICImagingFactory

My problem is, that i don´t know what exactly this interface id is, because i did not write any code for COM manually or using any image factory things or equal...

Im a bit lost atm...

May anyone tell me how to solve this and make it work with the static MFC usage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to guess what this linker error might have to do with MFC.  Nevertheless, Project + Properties, Linker, Input.  Additional Dependencies, add "windowscodecs.lib"

Comment: See a related discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9827214-c2d9-4261-a384-5b183917bf97/after-installing-vs-2010-sp1-im-getting-nafxcwdlibafxglobalsobj-error-lnk2001-unresolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IWICImagingFactory is defined in **wincodec.idl**

- Locate and add **wincodec.idl** to your MFC project
- Rebuild and MIDL compiler will generate **wincodec_i.c** and **wincodec_i.h**
- **wincodec_i.*** files contain the declaration and definition of _IID_IWICImagingFactory

Answer (score 30):

There is also a **.lib** file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\ **windowscodecs.lib**

Comment: The path on x64 is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib\windowscodecs.lib

Comment: I had to ensure windowscodecs.lib was actually added to the linker lib path to get past this issue

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't my exact problem (different .idl), but same linker error. Google found your question anyway. I copied the .idl file out to a new directory, launched a VS command line, and ran this:

```
midl thefile.idl
```

After it made my .c file, I just copied the const for the IID that I needed, and threw away the rest.